# Tensor._shape is private, use Tensor.shape instead

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I use tensorflow 1.14.1 with keras functional API and I need to do an interpolation at the end of decoder part of my network. After running the following code an error appears:

```
conv_layer = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', data_format='channels_first')(bn_pre)
act_layer = LeakyReLU()(conv_layer)
prm_layer = Permute((2, 3, 1))(act_layer)
ld1_layer = Lambda(lambda x: tf.image.resize(x, [384, 384]))(prm_layer)
prm2_layer = Permute((3, 1, 2))(ld1_layer)
bn12_layer = BatchNormalization(axis=1, scale=False)(prm2_layer)
```

The error is:

```
W0116 17:40:42.326339 139793502861056 ops.py:465] Tensor._shape is private, use Tensor.shape instead. 
Tensor._shape will eventually be removed.
W0116 17:40:42.330794 139793502861056 ops.py:465] Tensor._shape is private, use Tensor.shape instead. 
Tensor._shape will eventually be removed.
```

Where tensor._shape is called? Should I care about this warning? and How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably the debugger. You don't have to care much.
check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31236)